Send a dm to a user when they leave from a server in discord.py - discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50007)
What I want to do
I'm creating a Discord bot using discord.py to study. I would like to send a dm to a user when they leave a server to which the bot belongs.

Problem
Sending by slash command works, but sending by on_member_remove() does not. The following error occurs.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\my-name\OneDrive\Desktop\test-app\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 449, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\my-name\OneDrive\Desktop\test-app\test_cog.py", line 11, in on_member_remove
    await self.send_farewell_dm(member)
  File "c:\Users\my-name\OneDrive\Desktop\test-app\test_cog.py", line 15, in send_farewell_dm
    await dm_channel.send("See you!")
  File "C:\Users\my-name\OneDrive\Desktop\test-app\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1618, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, params=params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\my-name\OneDrive\Desktop\test-app\.venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 752, in request
    raise Forbidden(response, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50007): Cannot send messages to this user


Here is my code
test_main.py
from test_bot import TestBot


def run() -> None:
    bot = TestBot()

    @bot.event
    async def on_ready() -> None:
        #load a cog file
        await bot.load_extension("test_cog")

        #Enable slash commands
        guild = bot.get_guild(123456789012345678) # dummy
        bot.tree.copy_global_to(guild=guild)
        await bot.tree.sync(guild=guild)
 
    bot.run("DICORD_BOT_TOKEN", root_logger=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()

test_bot.py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class TestBot(commands.Bot):
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(
            command_prefix = "!",
            intents = discord.Intents.all(),
            application_id = 987654321098765 # dummy
        )

test_cog.py
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands


class TestCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot:commands.Bot) -> None:
        self.bot = bot


    # Forbidden Error!
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_remove(self, member:discord.Member) -> None:
        await self.send_farewell_dm(member)

    async def send_farewell_dm(self, member:discord.Member) -> None:
        dm_channel = await member.create_dm()
        await dm_channel.send("See you!")


    # Success
    @app_commands.command()
    async def send_hello_dm(self, interaction:discord.Interaction) -> None:
        dm_channel = await interaction.user.create_dm()
        await dm_channel.send("Hello!")


async def setup(bot: commands.Bot) -> None:
    await bot.add_cog(TestCog(bot))


My working environment

Windows 11
VS Code
Python 3.12.5
virtualenv 20.26.5

Package            Version
------------------ -------
aiohappyeyeballs   2.4.1
aiohttp            3.10.6
aiosignal          1.3.1
async-timeout      4.0.3
attrs              24.2.0
charset-normalizer 3.3.2
discord.py         2.4.0
frozenlist         1.4.1
idna               3.10
multidict          6.1.0
peewee             3.17.6
pillow             10.4.0
pip                24.2
python-dotenv      1.0.1
yarl               1.12.1


What I tried
Discord's Privacy & Security
I checked my settings of Discord app. It seems ok.
My Privacy & Security Screenshot
DM to multiple users
I tried sending DM to 3 Discord accounts using on_member_remove(). Only one of them received it safely. Others did not. The error has occurred.

It would be appreciated if someone could help me resolve the error.

Your bot can only send private messages to a user if:

Your bot shares a server in common with the user;
The user has authorized direct messages to members of that server.

Note that when a member leaves your "dummy" server and that was the only server in common that your bot had with the user, it will no longer be allowed to send direct messages to the user.
When you try to send messages to a user you are not allowed on, you will get the error discord.errors.Forbidden.

You're trying to message a discord.Member which, according to the docs "Represents a Discord member to a Guild"
Since you're trying to message that user after they've left the server, there is no guild member to message.
Get the leaving member's ID, then fetch the discord.User, and then message them (Docs Reference). Also, handle any errors regarding not having enough permissions to message the user (such as Forbidden – You do not have the proper permissions to send the message.)
See this answer: "Discord.py Send DM to specific User ID"

Thank you for your answer. I was wondering why two of my accounts could not receive DMs from the bot while another one could. I fetched discord.User as your advice, but the error still occurred. By the way, the problem was resolved without doing anything. It seems that it took some time for the privacy&security settings to be reflected.

A Member object has the same effect as a User object when it comes to sending direct messages. The problem here is simply that the bot is no longer allowed to send direct messages to the member, as I explained in my answer.

The problem was resolved without rewriting the code. It seems that it takes some time for the privacy & security settings to be reflected. If you have the same error as me and have just changed your privacy & security settings, I suggest you wait a while, for example 24 hours.
Here are the settings I changed:

Privacy & Security > Direct messages from others > Show
Privacy & Security > Allow direct messages from server members > on


I tried sending DM to 3 Discord accounts using on_member_remove(). Only one of them received it safely. Others did not. The error has occurred.

That is why two of my accounts couldn't receive DMs from the bot. At that time I had just changed the settings.
